# Get entry of sub node from metadata

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I've the following code which is taking from the document the annotation, the problem is that it take only the first level of annotation but the annotation under the entity type are not fetched, any idea how to change the code to get also the annotation under the entity type?

http://jsfiddle.net/y6XgY/501/

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://services.odata.org/V4/(S(1j4xrnlnwnnmvagwtgl2envc))/TripPinServiceRW/$metadata',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('received data: ' + data);
        debugger;

        var annotations = jQuery(data).find("Annotations");
        var entityTypes = jQuery(data).find("EntityType");
        var entityAnnotation = jQuery(entityTypes).find("Annotations");

        console.log("annotations: " + annotations)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting

`var entityAnnotation = jQuery(entityTypes).find("Annotation");` *without* **s** at end of `.find("Annotation")`  for `var entityAnnotation = jQuery(entityTypes).find("Annotations");`

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y6XgY/502/